# Bash prefix string with tilde to expand to home directory

Tags: linux, bash, script, string-manipulation

I can't figure out how to prefix a string (e.g. "user1") with a tilde (~) to produce `~user1` and have that expand to user1's home directory.

Here is what I have now:

```
USER="user1"
ls ~${USER}
ls: cannot access ~user1: No such file or directory
```

`~user1` is not being expanded. How can I achieve it?

#### edit

This does not work:

```
$ cat test.sh
USER="user1"
ls $(~$USER)

$ sh -x test.sh
+ USER=user1
+ ~user1
test.sh: 1: ~user1: not found
+ ls
test.sh
```

Comment: Using `/home/user1` is not an option?

Comment: Don't use USER it is your name. Instead use lower case variables.

Comment: why should lower case be preferred?

Comment: so you don't overwrite the built in variables such as USER. USER holds the name of the current user that is executing the command.

Comment: ok so USER in particular is problematic, not all uppercase var names are. Thanks

Comment: yes but do you want to learn them all, and then keep up to date with all new ones. For this reason it is customary to have all local variables in shell scripts as lower-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your user's directory is not simply `/home/user`, you can use `eval` in your script ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358611/bash-get-users-home-directory-when-they-run-a-script-as-root)):

```
USER_HOME=$(eval echo ~${USER})
echo ${USER_HOME}
```

Comment: This works. Now, should I prefer `eval` or `bash -c`?

Comment: On second thought, I think that bash -c will start a new bash process so it will be **marginally** slower/more resource intensive.

Comment: While researching this, I found this link which explains what is happening and why eval is necessary: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion%3F

Answer (score 3):

This is a general way to get bash to re-evaluate, but the use of eval may be better as it will not spawn a new process. (echo is built into bash so not a new process)

```
user="user1"
bash -c "ls ~${user}"
```

Comment: 2nd way does not work. see my edit

Comment: This works. Now, should I prefer `eval` or `bash -c`?

Comment: eval is probably more portable as it does not care what the shell's name is.